# android how to draw graphics in existing layout

Tags: android

I have an existing xml layout and i am loading this layout in my activity class. Now i want to draw a rectangle in this at bottom.Which on clicking would call new intent.How do i add this rectangle to my existing layout.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chart);
```

this the code to draw the graphics.. How do i achieve this?

```
drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activities have nothing to do with drawing UI (in any case they never do this directly). View classes are responsible for drawing.

In your case you probably should extend `Button` class with your custom class. Override `onMeasure()` to make it square. And background will be anything you set it to be.

---

A quick example:

`SquareButton.java`:

```
package com.inazaruk.helloworld;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SquareButton extends Button
{
    public SquareButton(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(ctx, attrs);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(ctx, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);           

        /* currently view is rectangle, so we get the shorter size 
         * and make it square. */

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        width = height =(int) (Math.min(width, height));        

        super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
}
```

Layout that uses this button `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  a:orientation="vertical"   
  a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  a:layout_height="fill_parent"
  a:gravity="center" 
  a:weightSum="1">

    <com.inazaruk.helloworld.SquareButton
        a:id="@+id/button"
        a:layout_height="0dp"
        a:layout_weight="0.5"         
        a:layout_width="fill_parent"        
        a:background="#ffffffff" 
        a:text="foo" 
        a:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Screenshot of result:
[image]